# Passing a variable to an Ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I am using the code below to rotate and save an image stored on the server.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>

<img src="uploads/101822973264163759893-1428320267361.jpeg" id="img"/>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var value = 0
    $("#img").rotate({ 
       bind: 
         { 
            click: function(){
                value +=90;
                $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
            }
         } 

    });


    $(document).on('click', '#img', function() {
                // alert("Hello");

                var idno = "test";
                $.ajax({
                         url: "saveimage.php",
                         dataType: "html",
                         type: 'POST',
                         data: "panelid="+idno, //variable with data
                         success: function(data){
                            // $(".test").html(data);
                                // alert(data);
                         }
                });
    });
});
</script>
```

saveimage.php

```
<?Php
$degrees = -90;  //change this to be whatever degree of rotation you want

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$filename = 'uploads/101822973264163759893-1428320267361.jpeg';  //this is the original file

$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename) or notfound();
$rotate = imagerotate($source,$degrees,0);

imagejpeg($rotate,$filename); //save the new image

imagedestroy($source); //free up the memory
imagedestroy($rotate);  //free up the memory

?>
```

I found this code here - http://www.codehaven.co.uk/rotate-and-save-an-image-using-php/.

This all works fine but I am trying to pass a PHP variable which holds the image path and name to the ajax call and have no idea on how to do this.

Can anyone help?

thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the variable as URL parameters:

```
url: "saveimage.php?path=/folder/to/your/image/&image=image_name",
```

You can use urlencode to make sure all the special characters are pass through

Comment: Thanks! That was easier than I thought.